# app site association file on server is invalid

Tags: ios, deep-linking

I have an `apple-app-site-association` file on my website: https://getdad.co.uk/apple-app-site-association

I have followed many tutorials now, all slightly differing and universal app linking isn't working. I get this error message from Apple so I am assuming the problem is with the `apple-app-site-association` file:

[image: apple error]

From what I can see, I am doing this correctly. Can anyone see my problem?

Comment: Your `details` key should be an array, even though it only has one object in it. Compare: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you, I've changed that and it's being validated by branch.io but it's still appearing as invalid on the apple validator and still not working for deep linking

Comment: @Paulw11 it worked eventually! All I had to do was wait, thanks so much!!!